# Homestead Laravel problema com Drive Postgres

Tags: laravel, vagrant

Alguem aqui já teve esse com Homestead e postgreSql? A minha aplicação está dando esse erro.

PDOException
could not find driver

Já procurei em alguns locais mas nada...

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Tentou ativar pelo php.ini? no windows ou linux?

Comment: Já habilitou o driver? em `php.ini`: extension=php_pgsql.dll retire o ";" para habilitar e reinicie o serviço.

Comment: Sou novo com Nginx do Homestead. Onde fica o arquivo php.ini?

Comment: Estou usando o Homestead do jeito que veio. O Meu é Mac OS

Comment: @Edyonil `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Procure a partir desta pasta. Se estiver utilizando php5-fpm estará dentro da pasta fpm.

Comment: Obrigado juniorb2ss. Descobrir que o problema estava relacionado ao HHVM. Como sou novo com nginx, hhvm e vagrant, estou me mordendo um pouco. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Este erro ocorre pois a extensão não foi encontrada ou esta desativa.

Para ativá-la vá até:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/
```

Abra o arquivo php.ini, com editor que preferir.

Procure pela linha: extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll, caso esteja comentada, ou seja, com ";" no começo, remova-o e reinicie o serviço:

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Caso esteja utilizando apache efetue os mesmo passos, porém, na pasta:

```
/etc/php5/apache2
```

Caso não tenha a biblioteca, execute o comando:

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Reinicie o serviço.

Comment: Ola amigo, já está instalado. Aparentemente é algo com o HHVM, pois reconfigurei Homestead.yaml, removendo o HHVM. Ai funcionou.

Comment: Quando for assim, @Edyonil, você deve postar a solução como resposta da sua própria pergunta. Assim, você evita que a pergunta fique "aberta" (e alguém pense que você não solucionou o problema) e mostra uma solução para quem possa ter o mesmo problema :D